# How can I access my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm using EVW32C - Ubee Interactive router provided by my ISP. I want to get full access to the router and make a semi-API that will log currently connected devices (2.4GHz/5GHz/LAN connections) to my Raspberry Pi so I don't have to access the router's site all the time (e.g 192.168.0.1).

I tried SSH connection to my router through ssh user@public_ip which availed in no response. My options on the web access point are scant.

I searched for APIs available which are none, and I don't feel like using Selenium 24/7 since it's a waste of resources of my Pi or any other device.

Any other suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you asked your ISP about access?

Comment: If you're leasing this from the ISP, they hold the keys, and will also have instructions on how to connect, if it is possible. In general, I avoid paying ISPs for modems or routers. If I must use an ISP modem, I purchase my own router that I retain full control of that my entire network runs through.

Comment: I've asked my ISP for help but they said that there is nothing they can do. I talked to their support team, but they won't let me talk to their IT team.

Comment: Put in a new router of your own and connect it to your ISP.. Then connect all other gear to the new router and administer it that way.

Comment: why don't you just use nmap on another machine? saves far too much grief.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you actually purchased the modem, you don't own it. In all likelihood, your ISP owns the modem you are using, and you're paying for the privilege of using it.

You will not be able to get into it unless they allow you to.

The correct way to solve this is to purchase your own router, connect THAT to the modem, and then construct your network using the router you fully own and control as the main connection point.